# combine fields in elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Suppose I have a table in SQL where I combine two fields as one

```
A    |     B
-----|--------         => select A+' '+ B as Name => BMW X-Series
BMW  |   3-Series
BMW  |     X3
```

I dump it into a temp table and I do a wildcard search on the temp table which returns the result with count

```
select Name,count(Name) as frequency from Table where Name like '%3%' group by Name

     Name        Frequency
     ------------------  
    BMW 3-Series |  1
    BMW  X3      |  1
```

Now how do I achieve the same is elasticsearch given that A and B are seperate fields.

I tried this:

```
{ "query":{
      "query_string":{
          "fields":["A","B"],
          "query":"3"
      }
      }, "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "A"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "B"
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

How do I add regular expression on the query

Comment: you can just use "query":"*3*" regular expressins analyzed by default. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key difference between SQL and Elasticsearch is that by default, string fields are analyzed *at index time*, and you can control how they are analyzed with [Analyzers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-analyzers.html).

The default analyzer, [the Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), will produce tokens from the input and store these in an inverted index. You can see what tokens would be generated for a given input by using the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard" -d'
{
  text : "3-Series"
}'
```

which yields the output

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "3",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "series",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Knowing this, using a search query that undergoes analysis *at search time* such as [the Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), there is no need for [regular expression queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) or [wildcard queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) *if* you analyze the input in a way to support your use cases.

You may decide to index "BMW 3-Series" in one field and analyze it in different ways using [multi_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields_2), or keep the values in separate fields as you have and search across both.

Here's an example to get you started. Given we have the following POCO

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

We can set up the following index

```
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var carsIndex = "cars";
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(carsIndex);

var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

client.CreateIndex(carsIndex, ci => ci
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(analysis => analysis
            .Tokenizers(tokenizers => tokenizers
                .Pattern("model-tokenizer", p => p.Pattern(@"\W+"))
            )
            .TokenFilters(tokenfilters => tokenfilters
                .WordDelimiter("model-words", wd => wd
                    .PreserveOriginal()
                    .SplitOnNumerics()
                    .GenerateNumberParts()
                    .GenerateWordParts()
                )
            )
            .Analyzers(analyzers => analyzers
                .Custom("model-analyzer", c => c
                    .Tokenizer("model-tokenizer")
                    .Filters("model-words", "lowercase")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Car>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .String(s => s
                    .Name(n => n.Model)
                    .Analyzer("model-analyzer")
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

We create a `cars` index and create a custom analyzer to use for the `Model` field. This custom analyzer will separate the input into tokens on any non-word character, with token filters that will then split each token on numerical characters to generate a token that preserves the original token, tokens that represent the number part(s) and a tokens that represent the word part(s). Finally, all tokens are lowercased.

We can test what the `model-analyzer` will do to our inputs, to see if it is suitable for our needs

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/cars/_analyze?analyzer=model-analyzer" -d'
{
  text : "X3"
}'
```

produces

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "x3",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "x",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "3",
      "start_offset": 1,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/cars/_analyze?analyzer=model-analyzer" -d'
{
  text : "3-Series"
}'
```

produces

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "3",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 1,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "series",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

This looks suitable for the problem at hand. Now, if we index some documents and perform a search, we should get the results we're looking for

```
client.Index<Car>(new Car { Make = "BMW", Model = "3-Series" });
client.Index<Car>(new Car { Make = "BMW", Model = "X3" });

// refresh the index so that documents are available to search
client.Refresh(carsIndex);

client.Search<Car>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Fields(f => f
                .Field(c => c.Make)
                .Field(c => c.Model)
            )
            .Query("3")
        )
    )
);
```

yields the following results

```
{
  "took" : 4,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.058849156,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "cars",
      "_type" : "car",
      "_id" : "AVTbhENDDGlNKQ4qnluJ",
      "_score" : 0.058849156,
      "_source" : {
        "make" : "BMW",
        "model" : "3-Series"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "cars",
      "_type" : "car",
      "_id" : "AVTbhEOXDGlNKQ4qnluK",
      "_score" : 0.058849156,
      "_source" : {
        "make" : "BMW",
        "model" : "X3"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Hope this has given you some ideas.